# Is there a notion of tensor-completion of a category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories

Given an additive category $\mathcal{C}$, sometimes one wants to consider its **Karoubi envelope** or **idempotent completion**  $\mathrm{Kar}(\mathcal{C})$, whose objects are summands of objects in $\mathcal{C}$. So for instance, if $X\in Ob(\mathcal{C})$, and $X\cong A\oplus B$, then $A$ and $B$ are objects in $\mathrm{Kar}(\mathcal{C})$. Formally, the object $A$ in $\mathrm{Kar}(\mathcal{C})$ is defined as a pair $(X,e_A)$, where $e_A\in \mathrm{End}(X)$ satisfies $e_A^2=e_A$.

In my situation, I have a $k$-linear, abelian, symmetric monoidal category $(\mathcal{D},\oplus,\otimes)$, and I want to consider a new category $\mathrm{Ten}(\mathcal{D})$ whose objects include **tensor factors** of objects of $\mathcal{D}$, that is, if $X\cong A\otimes B$ in $\mathcal{D}$, I would like to view $A$ and $B$ as objects in $\mathrm{Ten}(\mathcal{D})$.

> Does such a $\mathrm{Ten}(-)$ exist? How is it formally defined?

Comment: Hard to say if that makes sense since there are no interesting morphisms between A and X.

Answer (score 4):

The obstruction to making this work is that biproducts are a *property* -- having $A \oplus B \cong C$ means there exist morphisms $A, B \to C$ and $C \to A,B$ satisfying some axioms. Then you can look at what this means about $C$: you get two idempotent endomorphisms of $C$, which are the projections onto the two factors. Now we know that biproduct factors, when they exist, come from idempotent endomorphisms, and so the definition of Karoubi envelope becomes clear!

On the other hand, a general symmetric monoidal structure is truly a *structure*, and not a property. In other words, having $A \otimes B \cong C$ in a symmetric monoidal category does not tell you anything about the morphisms in your category, so it's hard to say what the "tensor envelope" should be.